# Camera permissions for Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to receive Camera permissions for Chrome Extensions (not an app!)? If so, what do we need to do?

I have looked around but I cannot seem to find a straight answer about using cameras for chrome extensions.

Comment: you want open camera on clicking the brows button right?

Comment: when you click on the icon for the chrome extension, I want the camera to open automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need HTML5 with a little bit of javascript to get access to the camera. Refer to [this link](https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera)

```
<!--
    Ideally these elements aren't created until it's confirmed that the 
    client supports video/camera, but for the sake of illustrating the 
    elements involved, they are created with markup (not JavaScript)
-->
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

The javascript:

```
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });
}
```

Comment: I already have this working, I am having trouble turning it on though immediately when you click on the extension icon in the top right. though I keep getting an error about inline scripting.

Comment: post the error here... or update your question with the error

Comment: I also want to camera access with chrome extension.

There is some error "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: Failed due to shutdown"